# Kendo UI grid won't populate from ajax dataSource MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to populate kendo grid with my model from ajax call. This is my Kendo Ui Grid with Html.Helpers in .cshtml

```
<div id="grid">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<OtpadModel.AddressObject>()
.Name("Grid")
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Selectable(sel =>
{
        sel.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single);
})
.Filterable()
.Scrollable()
.Events(events => events.Change("onChange"))
.Groupable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetAddressObjects", "AddressObject"))
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID)))
.Columns(columns => {
    columns.Bound(p => p.KeyNumber).Title("Šifra objekta");
    columns.Bound(p => p.ObjectType.Type).Title("Vrsta objekta");
    columns.Bound(p => p.ObjectOwners.FirstOrDefault().Owner.Name).Title("Ime vlasnika");
    columns.Bound(p => p.ObjectOwners.FirstOrDefault().Owner.Surname).Title("Prezime vlasnika");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Address.Street).Title("Ulica");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Address.Number).Title("Broj");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Address.City.Name).Title("Grad");
    columns.Bound(p => p.ResidentalArea).Title("Površina");
    columns.Bound(p => p.ResidentsNumber).Title("Članovi");
    columns.Bound(p => p.TuristBedsNumber).Title("Turistički kreveti");
})   
)
</div>
```

My controller method implementation is:

```
    public ActionResult GetAddressObjects([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        IEnumerable<AddressObject> addressObjects = unitOfWork.AddressObjectRepository.Get(includeProperties: "ObjectType, Address, ObjectOwners");
        DataSourceResult result = addressObjects.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);           
    }
```

I have all refernces. I can populate from my server side, so when I write Grid(Model) grid is populated but I don't want this.

Comment: Have you tried debugging in Fiddler to see if your action is being called? Also try adding an error handler .Events(e => e.Error("error_handler")) and create the javascript function.

Comment: Yes I have. My action is being called and my addressObjects and result variables in controller are populated correctly.

Comment: "so when I write Grid(Model) grid is populated but I don't want this." I'm confused what is the question?

Comment: Question is: When i populate my grid from Model that I pass to the View - Viwe(myPopulatedModel) then Grid(Model) in my view, it is populated. I cannot have Server side population because of some restrictions, so it needed to be populated on client side using Ajax. And that does not work, even though my Action in Controller is invoked and populated

Comment: Are you certain that `read.Action("GetAddressObjects", "AddressObject")` is correct?

Comment: Start simple, remove the paging, filtering, events etc. Remove all columns apart from 1, KeyNumber, and see if it works.

Comment: I am not able to found any issue in your code. As you have already told, controller method return the result successfully. So, the issue is in the client side. Temporary remove all columns and add only "ID" in your grid. If it shows the ID columns data in grid then something wrong in any other column. by using console window of browser please make sure there is not any javascriopt error in your page.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your huge help. The problem was that one of my classes had one virtual property and the problem is that virtual keyword. You cannot have anything virtual, map always to ViewModel. But accidentally, one of my properties in my ViewModel was virtual (copy, paste mistake).

Answer (score 0):

Set the property autobind to false.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<OtpadModel.AddressObject>()
.Name("Grid")
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Selectable(sel =>
{
        sel.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single);
})
.AutoBind(false)
.Filterable()
.Scrollable()
.Events(events => events.Change("onChange"))
.Groupable()
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetAddressObjects", "AddressObject"))
    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID)))
.Columns(columns => {
    columns.Bound(p => p.KeyNumber).Title("Šifra objekta");
    columns.Bound(p => p.ObjectType.Type).Title("Vrsta objekta");
    columns.Bound(p => p.ObjectOwners.FirstOrDefault().Owner.Name).Title("Ime vlasnika");
    columns.Bound(p => p.ObjectOwners.FirstOrDefault().Owner.Surname).Title("Prezime vlasnika");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Address.Street).Title("Ulica");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Address.Number).Title("Broj");
    columns.Bound(p => p.Address.City.Name).Title("Grad");
    columns.Bound(p => p.ResidentalArea).Title("Površina");
    columns.Bound(p => p.ResidentsNumber).Title("Članovi");
    columns.Bound(p => p.TuristBedsNumber).Title("Turistički kreveti");
})
```

Then, in your document ready or some other page event, execute this code:

```
var grid = $("#yourgridElementName").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.read();
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: Have you had this work for you before? What I mean is, is this an issue that you have encountered before?

Comment: Not exactly the same problem as you, but I do currently bind some grids the exact way I explained to you using ajax binding. Once you set autobind to false, a call will not be made to the server. When you call 'grid.dataSource.read()' the call will be made as defined in your grid read action.